# How to set Kubeflow to use preemptible VMs?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow

I'm trying to set up a new Kubeflow deployment to use preemptible VMs. Referring to [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/preemptible-vms), I see that there is some YAML to specify preemptible nodes but I am not sure where to put it in the myriad of YAML files generated by `kfctl.sh`. Meanwhile, going through the console, I see Preemptible nodes = disabled, but there is no way to change it.

How do I set the Kubeflow node pools to be preemptible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to change a node-pool from non-preemptible to preemptible.

What you can do is create a new preemptible [node-pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-pools) and [migrate](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool) the workloads from the non-preemptible node-pool to the new one.

By the other hand, you can go ahead and recreate the GKE cluster with a preemprible node-pool.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The `kfp.gcp` extension module has `gcp.use_preemptible_nodepool()`.
Check the [preemptible sample](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/091316b8bf3790e14e2418843ff67a3072cfadc0/samples/core/preemptible_tpu_gpu/preemptible_tpu_gpu.py#L39).